# scala-cats EitherT: chaining futures

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I am following [this](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/eithert.html). Structure of my program is:

```
(for {
        data <- myService.fetch(id).eitherT
        values <- anotherService.fetch(data.id).eitherT
        // todo: process values as part of forcomprehension
      } yield data.id).value
```

myService.fetch returns Future[...].

anotherService.fetch also returns Future[...], and values is a Seq.
I want to process entries in values using foreach

```
values.foreach(value => service.moreAction(value))
```

moreAction also returns Future[...]

Hence my aim is to chain it with previous Futures in for-comprehension itself.

What is idiomatic way of doing it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Cats if you want to go through all values of some data, apply some effect to them, and then get a data within this effect:

```
DataOf[A] => (A => Effect[B]) => Effect[DataOf[B]]
```

you use [`Traverse`](https://typelevel.org/cats/typeclasses/traverse.html) type class with its extension methods.

(Think of it like of generalization of `Future.sequence` which takes `Seq[Future[A]]` and returns `Future[Seq[A]]`, but one which performs `seq.map(toFuture)` and `Future.sequence` in one step).

```
import cats.syntax.traverse._

for {
  data <- myService.fetch(id).eitherT
  values <- anotherService.fetch(data.id).eitherT
  // Traverse is not available for Seq, it requires some specific data e.g. List
  result <- values.toList.traverse(value => service.moreAction(value).eitherT)
} yield result
```